# Grails rendering JSON

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I've just started working with Grails 2.4.4 and I'm trying to create a REST api which outputs JSON but I have a problem with it when it comes to render the object as JSON. Listed below are the domain class, controller and the objectmarshall.

Domain class :

```
@Resource(uri='/users')
class User {
List contacts;
String name;
String password;
static hasMany=[contacts:Contact]
static constraints = {

}

static mapping = {
    contacts lazy: false
}
}
```

Controller :

```
class UserController {

def index() {
    //json
    render User.getAll() as JSON
}
```

Boostrap groovy :

```
class BootStrap {

def init = { servletContext ->
    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(User) {
        def output = [:]
        output['id'] = it.id
        output['name'] = it.name
        output['contacts'] = it.contacts
        return output;
    }
    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Contact) {
        def output = [:]
        output['id'] = it.id;
        output['name'] =it.name;
        output['phoneNumber'] = it.phoneNumber;
        output['userId'] = it.user.id;
        return output;
    }   
    }
    }
```

After I run my application the first time,it returns XML instead of JSON but if I make a new change that will generate a hot deploy(for e.g if I add a comment) it will generate JSON.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare content type with `render(contentType:"application/json")`

Answer (score 1):

I find creating a map of what you want and rendering that is much simpler.

```
def renderMe = [name: "Joe"]
render renderMe as JSON
```

Comment: what has actually fixed my problem was to remove the @Resource annotation. It seems that there was some kind of conflict between the annotation and the `render as` method